# How to increment multiple rows using SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

How to update multiple records with incrementing some field (in my case `id`)?
I missed one record and the whole table shifted.

How to do that in one transaction or one query? Or what is the fastest way to do that?

Tried something like below, but it is too slow.

```py
rows = session.query(Table).all()
for row in rows:
    row.id = row.id + 1
    session.commit()
```

Also tried to use something like, but it's not working for me:

```
session.query(Table)\
    .filter(Table.id == row.id)\
    .update({'id': row.id + 1})
```

Example of data I have:

```
 ID   Value 
  1       A
  2       B
  3       C
               < -- D is missing here
  4       E
  5       F
```

Here, if it would be alphabet `D` should have ID=4, then I need to increment `E` and `F`.

It is not something complicated when you have 5 records, but problem occurs when you have millions or billions of records with this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "whole table shifted"? Are you aware that PostgreSQL serials/identity can have holes by design? Please provide a [mcve], in this case the model, and some sample data from before and after what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @IljaEverilä and actually I need to create that hole in solid sequence. Because I missed to create one object during import. But objects should go one by one.

Comment: @IljaEverilä added example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to insert a document inside sequence,
I manually created `new_id` column and added it to `Table` model

```
new_object_id = 4

session.query(Table) \
    .filter(Table.id < new_object_id)\
    .update({Table.new_id: Table.id})

session.query(Table) \
    .filter(Table.id >= new_object_id)\
    .update({Table.new_id: Table.id + 1})
```

After these actions, you should be able to see a "hole" in id-sequence.

Then, in separate queries, manually renamed columns `id` -> `old_id` and `new_id` -> `id`.
Updated newly "created" `id` column with all attributes (primary key, unique, etc.).
Dropped `old_id` column.

And finally, inserted the required row.

Total time - few minutes, instead of few days.

*Found solution that works for me by myself.

If anybody knows how to optimize manual steps - you are welcome to add comments or edit this answer.*